# Passing data and actualize button title

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

In my app I have a view called `StudentAddHistoryPlanningController`, which contains two buttons. I have no problem with the the first button, which takes the value of a picker date,ut the second button called `lbWorkPointSelectionButton` opens a table view with a list of subjects.  I'm trying without success to change the second button's title to match the subject selected in that table view.

This is a bit of the code of my second table view :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    pointSeleted =  names[indexPath.row]
    handlePointSelected()
}

func handlePointSelected(){

    let historyController : StudentAddHistoryPlanningController = StudentAddHistoryPlanningController ()

        historyController.lbWorkPointSelectionButton.setTitle(pointSeleted, for: .normal)
        historyController.lbWorkPointSelectionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(r: 101, g: 99, b: 164), for: .normal)
        historyController.lbWorkPointSelectionButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 101, g: 99, b: 164).cgColor

    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Comment: everytime you tap the cell you create the new instance of StudentAddHistoryPlanningController.  you can do it with closure.

Comment: You create your `historyController`, assign some values, and then let it fall out of scope.  (Actually, I'm a little surprised it doesn't crash on `historyController.lbWorkPointSelectionButton` because the way you create the controller doesn't even load it from a storyboard.)

Comment: thx for your responses. But i dont understand what I have to do I'm very noob. And I dont have storyboard everything is done programmatically

Comment: OK, that explains the lack of a crash.  However, there's still a problem in that you're creating a `StudentAddHistoryPlanningController` instance and then not displaying it.  If you already have a different instance of `StudentAddHistoryPlanningController` maybe you should be changing its button instead of creating a new controller object.